# Regex: How to insert text before the first line and after the last line of file

Tags: regex, text-files, notepad

I needed to add a php script on the beginning of 2000 files. So, I find the solution, maybe this will help anyone to do this with regex.

Comment: Is this a self answer to a question? If yes then Remove the answer part from the question and post it as an answer.

Comment: hello, yes, I post it as an answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you have to select the first line on text: `^\A(.*)$`

Then, search and replace like this:

Search: `^\A(.*)$`

Replace By: `ANY_TEXT \r$1`

I use GrepWin to replace a big text, not just a single line. Remember that \r or \n are use to add a new line. If you don't want to use one of those, you will be able to add anything at the beginning of first line, without space it by another line  `ANY_TEXT $1`

Another way to to this:

Search: `\A(?-s){1}(?s)(.*)`

Replace By: `ANY_TEXT \r$1`

And another way:

Search: `(?s)(.*)`

Replace by: `ANYTHING \n\1`

**Now, if you want to add something at the end of first line:**

Search: `^\A(.*)\K$`

Replace with: `ANY_WORDS`

**And, finally, if you want to add something after the last line on text:**

Search: `^(.*)$\z`

Replace by: `$1 \nANY_WORDS`

Answer (score 0):

`^\A(.*)$` did not work for me in all case since I sometimes had something like an = at the beginning of the text. `^(.*)$` helped to pick up everything.